# G++ flag to protect against use of uninitialized inherited properties

Tags: c++, inheritance, g++, compiler-flags

How can I make g++ to protect me against the use of uninitialized parent properties into child constructor ?

```
struct A {
    A(int typ): type{typ} {}
    const int type;
};

struct B : public A {
    B(int typ): A(type) {}
};

int main() {
    B b{3};
    return 0;
}
```

Can you see the bug here, how tricky it is ?
Here we build an instance of `B` with `3` as parameter we expect that the value of `type` into `A` is `3`, right ? But we have done a typing mistake into `B` constructor, and we do not pass the content of the received parameter to `A` but the content of the value already in `A::type`. See the difference `typ` vs `type` in `B` constructor.

So how can I make g++ to warm me against this ? Because it shouldn't be allowed, `A` is not already initialized, we shouldn't be able do access `A` properties.

Comment: Not a warning, but if you give the constructor parameter the same name as the member, then the constructor parameter will be used as it hides the parents class member.

Comment: `-Wuninitialized`: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/5rMPah

Comment: @NathanOliver indeed, but that is why I said a typing mistake

Comment: I get that, but if they are named the same then a typing mistake becomes a compiler error (name does not exist) instead of silently compiling.

Comment: @dyp it doesn't seem to work, the flag does nothing for me, have you an idea of the reason ?

Comment: It would be great if you could set it up on the compiler-explorer to reproduce the issue that `-Wuninitialized` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Always use `-Wall -Wextra` as a start. Captures quite some problematic code and avoids quite some questions ;-)

Comment: @OlafDietsche these flags was used ;)

Comment: Then I don't see why you're asking this question, because this is already sufficient to get two warnings: 1. unused `typ` 2. uninitialized `type`

Comment: Yes for the unused `typ` but as I had answered this is not sufficient to get the unitialized warning and I wanted to get this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag to use is `-Wuninitialized`, it is already embedded with `-Wextra` and `-Wall`.

But in my case, I use gcc-6.4 in c++14 mode.
With this gcc version you have to use the flag, enable optimization and use the variable that have been initialized with an uninitialized variable.
Only if all of these condition have been done, gcc will warn you about used of uninitialized variable.

You can see this here : https://compiler-explorer.com/z/q53sYr - If I remove the `-O2` flag or the last condition on `b.type`, gcc will not warn us.

As the man page say (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/g++.1.html) :

> Note that there may be no warning about a variable that is
> used only to compute a value that itself is never used,
> because such computations may be deleted by data flow
> analysis before the warnings are printed.

Comment: Well, the warning about the unused parameter is also a good hint...